# JSON to CSV in Specific Format

Tags: python, json, csv

I am trying to Convert a Json file to Csv

I am not able to build the logic.
This is what i tried

**CODE**

```
import json
import csv
import os

with open('truck_trips.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

file_path = 'json_data.csv'
    
if not os.path.exists(file_path):
    print("No File")
    header = ['Truck_Id', 'Trip_Id', 'Start', 'End']
    with open(file_path, 'w') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(header)
    
    for item in data:
        print(item)
        for t in data[item]:
            print(t)
            print(data[item][t])
        print("\n")
```

Comment: I wont download this unknown link, try to add a [minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with a sample of your data.

Comment: Am I dumb that I downloaded it without a thought?

Comment: It's not a good idea to post sample data as a downloadable link on an upload server, with an expiry of 6 days. I would cut down the input data to absolute minimum, and put in a collapsible section:  `<!-- begin snippet: js hide: true --> stuff-to-hide <!-- end snippet -->`. Doing so will avoid external links, and still keep question relatively short.

Comment: Sorry but i am not able to add the data here it says to many code add some words but it is still saying the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the job,

```
# Getting the JSON content.
with open("/content/truck_trips.json", "r") as f:
  json_output = f.read()

output_dict = json.loads(json_output)

# Storing the relevant data from the JSON file into a list.
trucks_detail = []

for truck in output_dict:
  for trip in output_dict[truck]:
    trips = output_dict[truck][trip]

    for i in range(len(trips)):
      start, end = trips[i][0], trips[i][1]
      truck_detail = [truck, f"{trip}.{i + 1}", start, end]
      trucks_detail.append(truck_detail)

# Converting it into a dataframe.
df = pd.DataFrame(trucks_detail, columns = ["Truck_Id", "Trip_Id", "Start", "End"])
df.to_csv("Truck Details.csv", index = False)
```

The dataframe,

|  | Truck_Id | Trip_Id | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | truck_1 | trip_1.1 | Toronto | Kitchener |
| 1 | truck_1 | trip_1.2 | Kitchener | Cobourg |
| 2 | truck_1 | trip_1.3 | Cobourg | Aylmer |
| 3 | truck_1 | trip_1.4 | Aylmer | Owen Sound |
| 4 | truck_1 | trip_1.5 | Owen Sound | Orillia |
| 5 | truck_1 | trip_1.6 | Orillia | Toronto |
| 6 | truck_1 | trip_2.1 | Toronto | Ottawa - Gatineau |
| 7 | truck_1 | trip_2.2 | Ottawa - Gatineau | Welland - Pelham |
| 8 | truck_1 | trip_2.3 | Welland - Pelham | Toronto |
| 9 | truck_1 | trip_3.1 | Toronto | Fort Frances |